# I am trying to short Employee according to firstname but I am getting this error?

Tags: java, collections

I am getting the error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException
:  com.genous.Employee cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

at java.util.Arrays.mergeSort(Arrays.java:1157)

at java.util.Arrays.sort(Arrays.java:1092)

at java.util.Collections.sort(Collections.java:134)

at com.genious.Employee.main(Employee.java:54)//

```
public class Employee implements Comparator
{
String firstname;
String lastname;
int mobileno;
public Employee(String firstname,String lastname,int mobileno)
{
this.firstname=firstname;
this.lastname=lastname;
this.mobileno=mobileno;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
        return firstname;
}


@Override
public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
Employee e2=(Employee)o1;
Employee e3=(Employee)o2;
int i=e2.firstname.compareTo(e3.firstname);
if(i!=0)
    return i;

return i;
}


/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
ArrayList list=new ArrayList();
    Employee e=new Employee("anand","pandey",93456666);
    Employee e1=new Employee("sheel","nidhi",678956344);
    Employee e5=new Employee("shumit", "Kumar", 97390267);
    Employee e6=new Employee("Kamal", "Kumar", 97390267);
    list.add(e);
    list.add(e1);
    list.add(e5);
    list.add(e6);
    System.out.println(list);
Collections.sort(list);
    System.out.println(list);
}



}
```

Comment: How are you going to identify whether one employee is equal to another or not? If you want only unique elemetns to be stored, use sets . If duplicate employees are allowed, use list

Comment: Why on Earth would you have a database of millions of records in an ArrayList instead of, you know, a relational database.  Not only would performing a query against an RDBMS catalog be far easier, but it would be far more system resource friendly and far more robust.  It seems like you are using the wrong tools to solve what is otherwise a very common and ordinary problem.

Comment: You better to do so in your DB. It will use less resources and took much less time

Comment: Yea but one company interview asked me to do this with ArrayList ,I provided solution with Hashmap and Set but she insisted me to do in ArrayList,I can go with various ways but I need answer in ArrayList.

Comment: If it is an interview question you should write about it. Then the society will understand that the question is not how to do this in common. The question is how to do this using only ArrayList as data structure. This is more about algorithm

Comment: @Envious, If I was interviewing there and they told me to use an ArrayList, I would say that they did not know how to program and would not want to work there.

Comment: @gunr2171 They use questions like that to see how can you estimate complexity of your solution. Not to use it in production =)

Comment: You should say "*Hey we better use `LinkedList` cause operations are faster on big datas.* or you better say "*Hey, lets kill the Database architect!*"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can Override the `equals()` method in your employee class and add all your employee objects to a set instead of List you will get the list of unique employee objects.And if you want the count of duplicate entries you can subtract set size() from List size()

```
          //Provided you have overriden the equals() method
          List<Employee> employeeList = new ArrayList<Employee>();
          Set<Employee> employeeSet = new HashSet<Employee>(employeeList);

          int dupEntries = employeeList.size() - employeeSet.size();
          System.out.println("Dup Entries : "+dupEntries);
```

Comment: Yea Set have this property but I have told to do this in ArrayList so how we will do in ArrayList?But As I know set has not allow duplicate but there are three fields firstname,lastname,as you can see above,if you have proper answer then it will good with code?

Comment: Why you want to use the list?? when the set is providing that functionality and Though as i mentioned you should override the equals method() as you required, How you want to check for the euality.Set will compare the objects based  on the equals and hashcode

Answer (score 3):

Implement the Comparable interface

```
public class Empl implemnents Comparable{
  public int compareTo(Empl  o){
    if(.... your check if duplicate ....) 
      return 0;
    return -1;
  };
}
```

and try this

```
ArrayList<Empl> yourlist = ...;
TreeSet ts = new TreeSet();
ts.addAll(yourlist);
yourlist.removeAll(ts);
```

now yourlist has all duplicates. 
To override `equals()` is too low-level and offensive for myself.

Comment: if TreeSet is able to short then internally which basis will short,as employee should be unique,different employee may have same name?

Comment: (updated answer) what you ever like, write it into the clause.

Comment: Hey Peter Reader please see i have given some code.Why it is giving error.The o/p should come in shorted answer and I think you will like to give one look.